# Can I search multiple values in a "data-" element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple search input that filters divs as you type so that only those divs with matching data attributes are shown.

This works great, but it only returns exact matches. For example, in the snippet below, I can search for "apple" but "apple california" doesn't show the proper div (even though the data attribute contains both of those values). I think this is because it's only searching for an exact match.

How might I adjust this code to search for multiple values in a "data-" element? Ideally I'd like to have it ignore common words like "and," "in," "near," so that a search for:

**Apple in California** or **iphone near california**

would still show the Apple div.

Appreciate any advice, I'm stumped! Here's the snippet:

```js
$('[data-search]').on('keyup', function() {
  var searchVal = $(this).val();
  var filterItems = $('[data-filter-item]');

  if (searchVal != '') {
    filterItems.addClass('hidden');
    $('[data-filter-item][data-filter-name*="' + searchVal.toLowerCase() + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    filterItems.removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

input {
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
}

.items {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" data-search />
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div data-filter-item data-filter-name="apple+iphone+california">Apple</div>
    <div data-filter-item data-filter-name="google+nexus">Google</div>
    <div data-filter-item data-filter-name="microsoft">Microsoft</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can split the searchVal in multiple strings and save this in an array. Than make a search based on individual strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just grab all items and use `string.indexOf` on each item's data to check the presence of a string in a string.

```
$('[data-filter-item][data-filter-name]').each(function(element){
  var isPresent = $(this).data('filter-name').indexOf(searchVal.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  if(isPresent){
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: your code doesn't support the question requirements since it still looks for an **exact** match of the `searchVal`, and not partial match...

Comment: To expand on @RonenCypis point, one of the data attributes has the value `apple+iphone+california`. With your solution, if I search for `apple california` my search will return nothing. The values need to be separated and matched individually with the divs containing the most matches appearing first...

Comment: @RonenCypis Sure sure. But I never said to copy-paste the code. I did say _"use `string.indexOf` on each item's data to check the presence of a string in a string"_. How the OP uses that function is up to him.